# How to declare the datatype of date and year in SQLite?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm creating a SQLite database on python and am on the stage of creating tables. Within the table below I'm storing a date to an ID and need help with the datatype on the date. I'm not sure if there's an inbuilt one or if I do text and then format the date when inputting the data. I also have a similar question in another table but this type for storing the year. Thanks in advance.

Comment: SQLite doesn't enforce data types like other SQL technologies. Use `TEXT`.

Comment: You can use a check constraint to reject invalid values. But don't add them to the create table statement as those that exist there can not be changed without recreating the table.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite does not have an inbuilt date column type.

> 2.2. Date and Time Datatype SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And
>   Time Functions of SQLite are capable of storing dates and times as
>   TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER values:
>
> TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS"). REAL as Julian
>   day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November
>   24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar. INTEGER
>   as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.
>
> Applications can chose to store dates and times in any of these formats and freely convert between formats using the built-in date and time functions.

Column types in SQLite are very flexible and the type is largely irrelevant as you can store any type of data (INTEGER, REAL, TEXT, BLOB NULL) in any type of column (the one exception being the rowid column or an alias thereof (INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (with or without AUTOINCREMENT)) in which case the value must be an integer (64 bit signed)).

However, SQLite does have date and time functions that act on the data being stored in specific recognosed formats.

All the recognised date formats are directly sortable.

You may wish to have a look at :-

- [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)
- [SQL As Understood By SQLite - Date And Time Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)